# How to put a Button on top of my Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to put a button on top of panel by using C# code?

```
public partial class SpaceExplorer : Form
{
    Button btnPlayer = new Button();
    Panel pGame = new Panel();

    public SpaceExplorer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // panel: pGame
        pGame.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        pGame.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        pGame.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
        pGame.Name = "panelMain";

        Controls.Add(pGame);
    }

    private void subMenuStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // button: btnPlayer
        btnPlayer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 23);
        btnPlayer.Name = "player";
        btnPlayer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        btnPlayer.BackColor = Color.White;
        btnPlayer.Text = string.Empty;
        btnPlayer.Enabled = false;

        Controls.Add(btnPlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the button actually on the panel, or on the form above the panel? A few more details, please.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, I want the button on the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        panel1.Controls.Add(button1);
```

This will add `button1` on `panel1`